# State (Ed.) just once after all editors (not after every editor)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, custom-bib

I'm writing my master's thesis with latex and love it so far. My document class is scrbook and I'm using natbib for references. Since my institute has strict guidelines regarding the bibliography's appearance I've customized my bst-file regarding their needs. Last but not least there is one problem left. In case I have an article with multiple editors, "(Hrsg.)" is stated after every Editor. I need it to be a list of all editors separated by commas and after that just once stated "(Hrsg.)". Are there any advices how to put that into practice?

Following the part of my bst-file regarding the editor formatting is shown:

```
     FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
      { editor #1 "{ll}" format.name$ " (Hrsg.)" *
       editor num.names$ duplicate$
       #2 >
            $ ua.etal * }%% --->u. a.
        { #2 <
            'skip$
            { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
                { ua.etal }
                { "; " * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * " (Hrsg.)" * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
```

thx so much in advance for any solutions!

Julian